# Razor Class Library javascript is not executed

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a main .net core MVC Web app (TestRCL) which has a reference of a razor class library (Books). In TestRCL Program.cs I route the endpoints for the RCL.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "shop-default",
        areaName: "Books",
        pattern: "Books/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

I can correctly get the view Index.cshtml on http://localhost/Books/Home/Index but the Javascript is not executed. What am i missing ?

```
<div class="container shadow p-5">
    TEST
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log("Test")
    </script>
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a layout page and call like

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

in the layout page

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-2.2#sections) related

I tried as below,it works well:

[image]